# Remove ListView item highlight on tap Nativescript Angular iOS

Tags: ios, listview, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I would like to remove default behaviour on the ListView on iOS - highlight items on tap. I tried with setting the background color. And it didn't work out. I found this issue on github https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/455 
however I don't know how to achieve this in Angular nativescript

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the **itemLoading** event on the list view like this:

```
<ListView [items]="items" (itemLoading)="onItemLoading($event)">
```

Then in your typescript, define your **onItemLoading** event like this:

```
import { isIOS } from 'tns-core-modules/platform';
declare var UITableViewCellSelectionStyle;
// ...
onItemLoading(args: ItemEventData) {
  if (isIOS) {
    const iosCell = args.ios;
    iosCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
  }
}
```

FYI - I tested this on nativescript-angular version 3.1.0 and tns-core-modules version 3.3

Comment: how to set the none property style for android selection style